# Equal lifetimes for different objects in different places

Tags: rust

I have a struct `UrlShortener`:

```
pub struct UrlShortener {
    client: hyper::Client,
}
impl UrlShortener {
    pub fn new() -> UrlShortener {
        UrlShortener {
            client: hyper::Client::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn get(&self, url: &str) -> Result<String, Error> {
        let mut response = MyProvider.request(url, &self.client).send().unwrap();
        /// ...
    }
}
```

The `MyProvider` looks like this:

```
pub trait Provider {
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
    fn request(&self, url: &str, client: &hyper::Client) -> hyper::client::RequestBuilder;
}

pub struct MyProvider;
impl Provider for MyProvider {
    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        "myprovider"
    }

    fn request(&self, url: &str, client: &hyper::Client) -> hyper::client::RequestBuilder {
        client.get(&format!("http://example.com/create.php?format=simple&url={}", url))
    }
}
```

The I tried to compile it at first time it did not work:

```
src/lib.rs:21:16: 21:19 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements [E0495]
src/lib.rs:21         client.get(&format!("http://example.com/create.php?format=simple&url={}", url))
                             ^~~
src/lib.rs:20:5: 22:6 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn request<'a>(&'a self, url: &str, client: &'a hyper::Client)
 -> hyper::client::RequestBuilder
src/lib.rs:20     fn request(&self, url: &str, client: &hyper::Client) -> hyper::client::RequestBuilder {
src/lib.rs:21         client.get(&format!("http://example.com/create.php?format=simple&url={}", url))
src/lib.rs:22     }
error: aborting due to previous error
error: Could not compile `urlshortener`.
```

I've changed it according the compiler's advice and it is working okay.

```
fn request<'a>(&'a self, url: &str, client: &'a hyper::Client) -> hyper::client::RequestBuilder {
    client.get(&format!("http://example.com/create.php?format=simple&url={}", url))
}
```

The question here is why does it work? What is in my mind:

> `'a` lifetime for `self` in the `Provider` is different from the lifetime of `client: &hyper::Client` because these objects are in different places: `MyProvider` is on the stack and `client` is a field of the structure of the method I use.

So I think compiler compiles it successfully but it may lead to a runtime error or crash. Am I wrong?

"Correct" solution from my point of view would be:

```
fn request<'a, 'b>(&'a self, url: &str, client: &'b hyper::Client) -> hyper::client::RequestBuilder {
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So I think compiler compiles it successfully but it may lead to a runtime error or crash.

Unless you are using some `unsafe {}` code, this can't happen in Rust. Rust always statically checks bounds and it doesn't matter whether the variables are on stack or heap or are fields or whatever.

As for Rust's suggestions: since [`RequestBuilder`](http://hyper.rs/hyper/v0.9.9/hyper/client/struct.RequestBuilder.html) has a lifetime itself the following function:

```
fn request(&self, url: &str, client: &hyper::Client) -> hyper::client::RequestBuilder;
```

is equivalent to:

```
fn request<'a, 'b, 'c>(&'a self, url: &'b str, client: &'c hyper::Client) -> hyper::client::RequestBuilder<'a>;
//                      ^^                                                                                 ^^
```

because of the [elisions rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision). Note the important rule for that examples:

> If there are multiple input lifetimes, but one of them is `&self` or `&mut self`, the lifetime of self is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.

And that's when Rust gives you a misleading suggestion. In your function, the return value depends on `client` but not actually on `self`. Rust propose you to give `self` and `client` the same lifetime (ie. `'a == 'c`):

```
fn request<'a, 'b>(&'a self, url: &'b str, client: &'a hyper::Client) -> hyper::client::RequestBuilder<'a>;
//                  ^^                              ^^                                                 ^^
```

But it would be sufficient to have:

```
fn request<'a, 'b, 'c>(&'a self, url: &'b str, client: &'c hyper::Client) -> hyper::client::RequestBuilder<'c>;
//                      ^^                              ^^                                                 ^^
```

which can be written with elision:

```
fn request<'c>(&self, url: &str, client: &'c hyper::Client) -> hyper::client::RequestBuilder<'c>;
//                                        ^^                                                 ^^
```