# Decoupling ownership from vector

Tags: rust, factory-pattern, mutable, borrow-checker, object-reference

I'm creating factory methods for objects with shared references. The compiler cannot see that the objects from a `Vec` are not referenced outside the local scope, and that the newly created objects are not linked to the original objects.

How do I get around this issue, what am I missing?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct A {}

pub struct B<'b> {
    a: &'b A,
}

impl<'b> B<'b> {
    pub fn new(a: &'b A) -> B {
        B { a: a }
    }

    pub fn combine(&self, _: &B) -> B {
        B::new(self.a)
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let a: A = A {};

    let mut v1: Vec<B> = vec![];
    v1.push(B::new(&a));
    v1.push(B::new(&a));

    let mut v2: Vec<B> = vec![];
    {
        let b1 = &v1[0]; // << Mutable borrow occurs here - why?
        let b2 = &v1[1];
        let c = b1.combine(&b2);
        v2.push(c)
    }
    v1.clear(); // Error: Cannot borrow due to mutable borrow above
    println!("{:?}", v2[0].a);
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v1` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:32:5
   |
27 |         let b1 = &v1[0]; // << Mutable borrow occurs here - why?
   |                   -- immutable borrow occurs here
...
32 |     v1.clear(); // Error: Cannot borrow due to mutable borrow above
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
33 |     println!("{:?}", v2[0].a);
   |                      -- immutable borrow later used here
```

No, sorry, I still do not quite get it.

Here is an even simpler example, without vectors:

```
    let a:A = A {  };
    
    let mut b1 = B::new(&a);
    let mut b2 = B::new(&a);
    
    let c = &b1.combine(&b2);
    //      ^^^ This creates a mutable reference to b1. How to avoid?
    b1 = B::new(&a);
    b2 = B::new(&a);
    
    println!("{:?}",c.a);
```

For some reason, the method call on the object will make the compiler assume that I have a reference to the object, despite `c` having no reference to `b1`. How do I get around that?

How can I declare the `combine()`-method to be immutable?

Comment: The compiler clearly states "immutable borrow occurs here" on the line you've marked as "Mutable borrow occurs here". Are you sure you are reading the errors correctly / have provided appropriate code?

Comment: You reference something in `v1`, put that reference into `B`, put that into `v2`, then try to delete the data in `v1`. That's a relatively clear example of trying to create memory unsafety. Why do you think this should work?

Comment: Perhaps you want `Vec::remove`, `Vec::swap_remove` or [How can I take ownership of a Vec element and replace it with something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33204273/155423).

Comment: I need to call methods on the objects in the Vec, but I do not need to keep references to the objects. All method calls are immutable, and no references outside the Vec is to be kept. Help understanding this is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is similar to [Rust lifetime error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41204134/3650362) or [Rust Lifetime mismatch in trait method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59522097/3650362), and perhaps less obviously [Equal lifetimes for different objects in different places](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38198829/3650362), in that the elided lifetimes in the signature of `combine` happen to not be what you wanted. Changing it to `-> B<'b>` should work.

Comment: I don't feel strongly enough about any one of those to dupe-hammer this question, so I will only *recommend* closing it as a duplicate of one of the questions I linked, if that indeed solves your problem. Thanks!